# cUrl doesn't send command immediately

Tags: linux, http, unix, curl

I'm trying to get a server response by simply calling `cURL http://my.url.com`. If I access the url via browser I get a response immediately. If I call it via curl It takes up to 3-4 seconds before I receive the response from the server.

Is there any kind of special "end" command which has to be passed to curl?

Comment: Did you also write the server side?

Answer (score 1):

You can run 'cURL -v http://my.url.com' with the verbose flag in order to see details of what step may be slow. Depending on the server the response can be fast or slow. For more details, check out the [man page of cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

Also, your browser may be storing pages which makes loading seem faster.

Comment: thx Jim, it was actually a DNS lookup problem. The URL I'm trying to access publishes its service through bonjour which somehow messes up things.